# Process hangs pinvoking AmsiScanBuffer from managed Code

Tags: c#, pinvoke, dllimport

I am attempting to use the [`AmsiScanBuffer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn889865(v=vs.85).aspx) function of the Windows Anti-Malware Service Interface from managed code, specifically C#.  When attempting to call the method the program hangs on the call anytime a non-zero buffer length is provided.  If a buffer length of 0 zero is provided then the method returns immediately with the HResult E_INVALIDARG.  The other methods exposed by AMSI work as expected so I expect the I believe my dllimport for this function to be close but probably not completely correct.  Besides the array copy approach represented here I have tried pinning the array and the behavior is identical.

**C prototype**

```
HRESULT WINAPI AmsiScanBuffer(
  _In_     HAMSICONTEXT amsiContext,
  _In_     PVOID        buffer,
  _In_     ULONG        length,
  _In_     LPCWSTR      contentName,
  _In_opt_ HAMSISESSION session,
  _Out_    AMSI_RESULT  *result
);
```

**Managed Code**

```
[DllImport("Amsi.dll", EntryPoint = "AmsiScanBuffer", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
public static extern int ScanBuffer(IntPtr amsiContext, IntPtr ptr, ulong length, string contentName, IntPtr session, out int result);

var virus = "X5O!P%@AP[4\\PZX54(P^)7CC)7}$EICAR-STANDARD-ANTIVIRUS-TEST-FILE!$H+H*";
var bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(virus);
int sizet = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(byte)) * bytes.Length;
var ptr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(sizet);

try
{
    Marshal.Copy(bytes, 0, ptr, bytes.Length);
    int hr = Amsi.ScanBuffer(context, ptr, (ulong)sizet, "Unknown Data", session, out result);
}
finally
{
    Marshal.FreeHGlobal(ptr);
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The main problem is the `length` parameter to `AmsiScanBuffer`. A `ULONG` in C/C++ on Windows is 32 bits, while a `ulong` in C# is 64 bits. So the parameter needs to be declared as a `uint`. I would have expected you'd get an "unbalanced stack" error when running under the debugger even if you passed a buffer length of zero. You can also declare `buffer` as a `byte[]` and then just pass in the `bytes` directly.

For further simplification, you can omit the `CallingConvention` since `StdCall` is the default. I also changed it to use the exact function name so it isn't necessary to specify it in the `DllImport`. In general, when I'm working with C libraries directly from C# I like to keep the original function names, e.g. `AmsiScanBuffer` instead of changing it to `Amsi.ScanBuffer`. This makes it easier to look up docs when somebody is working on the code, although this is of course a matter of taste.

Here's a working version as a console application.

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;

namespace AmsiTest {

    class Program {
        static void Main( string[] args ) {

            var virus = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(
                "X5O!P%@AP[4\\PZX54(P^)7CC)7}$EICAR-STANDARD-ANTIVIRUS-TEST-FILE!$H+H*"
            );

            IntPtr context;
            var hrInit = AmsiInitialize( "AmsiTest", out context );
            if( hrInit != 0 ) {
                Console.WriteLine( $"AmsiInitialize failed, HRESULT {hrInit:X8}" );
                return;
            }

            AMSI_RESULT result;
            var hrScan = AmsiScanBuffer(
                context, virus, (uint)virus.Length,
                "EICAR Test File", IntPtr.Zero, out result
            );

            AmsiUninitialize( context );

            if( hrScan != 0 ) {
                Console.WriteLine( $"AmsiScanBuffer failed, HRESULT {hrScan:X8}" );
            } else if( result == AMSI_RESULT.AMSI_RESULT_DETECTED ) {
                Console.WriteLine( "Detected EICAR test" );
            } else {
                Console.WriteLine( $"Failed to detect EICAR test, result {result:X8}" );
            }

        }

        public enum AMSI_RESULT { 
            AMSI_RESULT_CLEAN = 0,
            AMSI_RESULT_NOT_DETECTED = 1,
            AMSI_RESULT_BLOCKED_BY_ADMIN_START = 16384,
            AMSI_RESULT_BLOCKED_BY_ADMIN_END = 20479,
            AMSI_RESULT_DETECTED = 32768
        }

        [DllImport( "Amsi.dll" )]
        public static extern uint AmsiInitialize(
            string appName,
            out IntPtr amsiContext
        );

        [DllImport( "Amsi.dll" )]
        public static extern uint AmsiScanBuffer(
            IntPtr amsiContext,
            byte[] buffer,
            uint length,
            string contentName,
            IntPtr session,
            out AMSI_RESULT result
        );

        [DllImport( "Amsi.dll" )]
        public static extern void AmsiUninitialize(
            IntPtr amsiContext
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you sir this is definitely going the extra mile. The stylistic comments make sense.   In a non-abbreviated version of the code I favor the containing class name to be the library name which would lead to the redundancy of Amsi.AmsiInitialize.  So the trade off between readability and copy/paste ability when searching documentation.  As you say, purely as stylistic choice.

Comment: Wouldn't you know it, I made the same mistake myself with the `ulong` vs. `uint`. I decided to add the error checking on the `HRESULT` return value from `AmsiInitialize` and `AmsiScanBuffer`, and I was getting nonzero results on calls that I knew were working. I noticed these results were 64-bit values with garbage in the high 32 bits and all zeroes in the low 32 bits. Sure enough, I had mistakenly declared the return values as `ulong`. Fixed now!

Comment: I wasn't running in visual studio so I didn't have debugger but I was surprised that an exception was not thrown.  I had anticipated that I would get some form of a memory access error if I was overrunning the buffer.  Either way this shows it has been far too long since I have written any C.

Comment: f for some reson the real-time protection enabled in Windows Defender Security Center is off you will get HRESULT 80070015 ... Edit to: 
if (hrScan == 2147942421) { Console.WriteLine( $"AmsiScanBuffer failed, HRESULT {hrScan:X8} Windows Defender Security Center Off!!! you need to have the real-time protection enabled in Windows Defender Security Center"); } else if (hrScan != 0) ...