# How to scan virus for Upload docs using Window defender in C#

Tags: c#, virus-scanning

I want to scan the uploaded document using c#. Currently, I'm using window defender in my Machine

Comment: Does this answer your question? [.NET virus scanning API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/975112/net-virus-scanning-api)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Windows Defender Antivirus scan from C# \[AccessViolation exception\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40888849/windows-defender-antivirus-scan-from-c-sharp-accessviolation-exception)